# What are KKT conditions for semi-infinite programming (SIP)?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am interested in the "most" simple form of the [semi-infinite programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-infinite_programming) (SIP):
\begin{align}
\min_{x\in \mathbb R^n} \hspace{0.5cm} & f(x)\\
\text{s.t.} \hspace{0.5cm} & \langle a(t), x\rangle \leq \lambda, \forall t\in T.
\end{align}
where

- $f: \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ is smooth convex, e.g. $f(x)=||y-x||_2^2$,
- $T$ is infinite, e.g. $T=[0,1]$
- $a: T\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ is continuous
- $\lambda>0$

Where I can find the [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) for such problem?

I tried to google:

- [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions): don't have KKT conditions
- [A book](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/239615692_Linear_semi-infinite_optimization): but this only talks about linear SIP, i.e. $f(x)=\langle c, x\rangle$.
- [An article](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Karush-Kuhn-Tucker-optimality-conditions-for-and-Tung-Tung/7e7715d00eb58ad43e31afbe5df397567c64262a): but this talks about non-smooth and multi-objective problems, which is very general, and of course too complicated for me.

Comment: Would the condition in this case be equivalent to $\sup_{t\in T} \langle a(t),x \rangle \le \lambda$? Then, if $\langle a(t),x \rangle$ is differentiable on $T$, we could find its $\max$ (or $\sup$) on $T$, substitute that as the condition, and write up the KKT conditions? It's just an idea.

Comment: @DanielP yeh 1 upvote. However I don't think that it is a good strategy. Let $g(t)=\sup_{t\in T} \langle a(t), x\rangle$, then the KKT conditions involve the gradient of $g$ and can not be evaluated explicitly.

Comment: The KKT conditions are going to be the same with the difference that the multipliers will depend on your parameter $t$. Check the literature on robust optimization, for instance.